# ViewSwitcher NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to set my Text in *TextSwitcher* based on which child in my *ViewFlipper* currently has focus and I keep getting a *null pointer*.
This may or may not important, but I have three text switchers in one activity each with a different view factory.

```
public void onSwipe(int direction) 
    {

        switch(direction)
        {

        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :
            UpdateTextSwitcher();
         if(flipper.getChildAt(flipper.getChildCount()-1).hasFocus())
         {   flipper.stopFlipping();
         Log.i("ARRAY_OnCreate", "True focus 1" );
         }
             else {
             flipper.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
             flipper.showNext();     
             }
         break;

        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT :
         if(flipper.getChildAt(0).hasFocus())
         {
            flipper.stopFlipping();
         }

             else{
             flipper.setInAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
             flipper.showPrevious();  
             }
         break;
        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :

         default:

             break;
      }
}

private void UpdateTextSwitcher()
{
    if (flipper.getChildAt(0).hasFocus())
    {
        lSwitcher.setText("R.string.s1");
        mSwitcher.setText("R.string.s2");
        rSwitcher.setText("R.string.s3");
    }
    else 
    {
        lSwitcher.removeAllViews();
        mSwitcher.setText("R.string.s2");
        rSwitcher.setText("R.string.s1");
    }
}
```

logcat shows

```
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at android.widget.TextSwitcher.setText(TextSwitcher.java:78)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at com.tmm.android.rssreader.RssActivity.UpdateTextSwitcher(RssActivity.java:134)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at com.tmm.android.rssreader.RssActivity.onSwipe(RssActivity.java:278)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at com.tmm.android.rssreader.SimpleGestureFilter.onFling(SimpleGestureFilter.java:119)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:568)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at com.tmm.android.rssreader.SimpleGestureFilter.onTouchEvent(SimpleGestureFilter.java:47)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at com.tmm.android.rssreader.RssActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(RssActivity.java:224)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    07-22 00:47:48.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11141):     at        dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why mSwitcher.setText(`"R.string.s2"`);? Shouldn't be just loading the string from resources`mSwitcher.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.s2));` Because if you set R.string.s2 without quotes .setText() will not accept (int), since requires CharSeq.

P.S: You don't need `break;` in `default` statement, and you need `break` in    `case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :`

Comment: Hmm. I didn't know that quotes were necessary when referencing resources. I've done it this way several times. Besides I've tried inserting the string directly for example `mSwitcher.setText("MyString")`, and still no luck

Comment: mSwitcher.setText("R.string.s2")  will out show you on the screen R.string.s2, just that, not the string inside the resource.

Comment: I see what you mean, that's a mistake I made when posting the question. But that shouldn't be the reason I am getting a `Null Pointer`, is it?

Comment: No it's not. Getting the child at `0` is what causes NPE. Make sure that it IS the child. Iterate through the childs (i hope childs > 1 :P) and check first if the child is not null, if it is not null then check for focus.

Comment: at android.widget.TextSwitcher.setText(TextSwitcher.java:78) Check if the textSwitcher is not null and make sure your not passing null argument to setText()